# Examples of distributed computing tasks relatively common among users

Tags: rendering, distributed-computing, blender, boinc

Can you give an example of such tasks?
I'm particularly interested in tasks, relevant to quite large amount of people, which could be solved by using distributed computing. (**Not a global projects, such as SETI@Home, Folding@Home, etc**)
As example we can take rendering and http://www.renderfarm.fi community.
Cryptocurrencies mining is not relevant.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Well, I don't know much about rendering, but when talking about tasks that can be solved by distributed computing, you will probably want to take a look on Bag-of-Tasks (BoT) applications.

> "Bag-of-Tasks applications (those parallel applications whose tasks are
>   independent) are both relevant and amendable for execution on computational grids. In fact, one can argue that Bag-of-Tasks applications
>   are the applications most suited for grids, where communication can
>   easily become a bottleneck for tightly-coupled parallel applications."

This was taken from a paper that talks exactly about Bag-of-Tasks applications with grid computing. You can [read the full paper here](http://walfredo.dsc.ufcg.edu.br/papers/Grid%20Computing%20for%20BoT%20Applications%20v12.pdf).

Now finding a task relevant to users is a matter of creativity. [This list of distributed computing projects](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_distributed_computing_projects) might give you some insights.

Setting up the BOINC server and, mainly, programming the BOINC applications will be the hard tasks here. [This BOINC wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/BOINC) helps you to have a notion of what is needed on the "background" of a BOINC project.

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but fresh answer.

I have my own Distributed Computing Library written completely in C++ (search for gridman raspberry pi).

I am using it for:
 - Distributed Neural Networks training / validation
 - Distributed raytracing (for fun)
 - Distributed MD5 crunching (for fun)
 - Distributed WEP crunching (for fun)
 - Distributed WPA crunching (for fun)

And in general, i always think of it this way: If something takes too long time for me, then i split this into several PC's. Real world examples?

Take Investment Banking for example, all these models have to be calculated milion times with different parameters.

Take Neural Networks - a good example, learning takes ages (depends on data) - if you split this into 10 PC, your results are obtained 10 times faster.